# Stuck at changing the size of an SVG using Tailwind

Tags: svg, tailwind-css

I want to change this SVG's size using Tailwind CSS. I have taken this SVG from Google Symbols:

```
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        height="48"
        viewBox="0 -960 960 960"
        width="48"
        class="text-sm lg:text-2xl"
    >
        <path d="M795-120q-122 0-242.5-60T336-336q-96-96-156-216.5T120-795q0-19 13-32t32-13h140q14 0 24.5 9.5T343-805l27 126q2 14-.5 25.5T359-634L259-533q56 93 125.5 162T542-254l95-98q10-11 23-15.5t26-1.5l119 26q15 3 25 15t10 28v135q0 19-13 32t-32 13Z" />
    </svg>
```

But it does not work. I tried to remove `width` and `height` but then nothing was shown. I tried to change the `viewBox` to `0 0 24 24` based on Material UI, but again, nothing was shown.

How can I apply style on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the width and height attributes, then add the Tailwind CSS classes as required to set the new size.

Example

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" class="h-8 w-8" class="text-sm lg:text-2xl">
  <path d="M795-120q-122 0-242.5-60T336-336q-96-96-156-216.5T120-795q0-19 13-32t32-13h140q14 0 24.5 9.5T343-805l27 126q2 14-.5 25.5T359-634L259-533q56 93 125.5 162T542-254l95-98q10-11 23-15.5t26-1.5l119 26q15 3 25 15t10 28v135q0 19-13 32t-32 13Z" />
</svg>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/NzfXnSlETQ